# How to exclude parent block from group/ columns innerBlocks?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have created a custom block and used Gutenberg  component as inner/child blocks. It is working fine and t's not showing in it's inner blocks list but it is shown if I try to add inside a group/columns block. Is there a way to remove it?

Image 1: Parent not shown directly inside the block
[image: Parent not shown directly inside the block]

Image 2: Parent getting shown inside the group block created under parent block.
[image: Parent getting shown inside the group block created under parent block]

Answer (score 0):

When the child block is registered, define its [parent block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-registration/#parent-optional) which will restrict where the block can be inserted, eg:

```
registerBlockType('myproject/child-block', {
    ...
    parent: ['myproject/parent-block']
}
```

To take this a step further, you could create a main custom block that all your other blocks define as their parent thus disabling them from being added via group.